# I'm trying to test my code using pytest but i get 'command not found' in my terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it and nothing gives. Im using vscode by the way.  Any help will be appreciated.
This is the error message i get:[image]

I'm hoping to get some guidance on how to locate the package on my computer and place it in the correct path, as suggested by the error message, but im very new to python and not sure how to go about it.

Comment: `python -m pytest ...`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
`C:/Users/reham/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe -m pytest`

This is temporary solution. You should be able to run `python -m pytest`, but I guess this will fail if Python is not in PATH. You might want to [add Python to PATH](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows) if commands like `python` or `python -m ...` fail.